# Cannot read property "comments" of null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Below is my comment routes

```
 //comments new
router.get("/authorsCollections/travelCollections/blog/comments/new", function(req, res) {
    //find campground by id
    AuthorsCollection.findById(req.params.id, function(err, campground) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("comments/authornew", {
                campground: campground
            });
        }
    });

});



//comments create
router.post("/authorsCollections/travelCollections/blog", function(req, res) {
    //find campground by id
    AuthorsCollection.findOne({
        author: req.body.author
    }, function(err, campground) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/campgrounds");
        } else {

            Comment.create(req.body.comment, function(err, comment) {

                if (err) {
                    req.flash("error", "Something went wrong");
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    //add username and id to comment
                    comment.author.id = req.user._id;
                    comment.author.username = req.user.username;

                    //save comment
                    comment.save();

                    campground.comments.push(comment);
                    campground.save();
                    req.flash("success", "successfully added comment");
                    res.redirect("/authorsCollections/travelCollections/blog/index");
                }
            });

        }
    });
});
```

below is my author routes

```
router.get("/travelCollections/blog", function(req, res) {

    var author = {
        id: req.user._id,
        username: req.user.username
    };

    var newCampground = {
        author: author
    };

    AuthorsCollection.create(newCampground, function(err, newlyCreated) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("authorsCollections/travelCollections/blog/index", {
                campground: newlyCreated
            });
        }
    });

});
```

below is my views section

```
<div class="row">

    <div style="width: 30%; margin: 30px auto">
        <form action="/authorsCollections/travelCollections/blog" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="comment[text]" placeholder="text">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-default btn-block">Submit!</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <a href="/campgrounds">Go back</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

below is my schema

```
var authorsCollectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    },

    comments: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Comment"
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("AuthorsCollection", authorsCollectionSchema);
```

When I post some comment in the views section I am getting `cannot read property comments of null` when I look inside the db I could see this results.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5b3f4b813b663f1e38428232"),
    "author": {
        "id": ObjectId("5b1631f62289500fa7d0156d"),
        "username": "ramjive"
    },
    "comments": [],
    "__v": 0
}
```

My aim is to create a blog page wherein I will add contents and below is my comment section where user can write comments and comments will be displayed in the blog page.

Can anyone tell me how to solve it..

Comment: Somewhere your `campground` is being assigned a `null` value, so when `campground.comments` is called, you receive the error you noted. The error is telling you that the value `null` does not have a `comments` property available. Are you certain that your `findOne()` call is successfully retrieving a document?

Comment: yes findOne is retriving those values from the db mentioned above